# How can someone see all rows in sys.sysprocesses and not be SA?

Tags: sql-server

The only user that can see the entire sys.sysprocesses is the SA. Is there a role I can place a user (or any other way) that a user can be made a member of so the user can see the entire sys.sysprocesses -all the rows for all users not just the processes for the user executing the select.

I connect to many SQL Server instances with a dbo account. I need to know if someone is connected to the instance. I cannot get SA privileges.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by entire sys.sysprocesses. But you could create a view.

Comment: I think not only `sa` can see all processes,`If a user has VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the server, the user will see all executing sessions in the instance of SQL Server; otherwise, the user will see only the current session. `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql, or you can execute `sp_whoisactive` or `sp_who2`?

Comment: all rows in sys.sysprocesses.

Comment: I cannot create a view and cannot grant myself view server status on many machines that I am connecting to.

Comment: `processadmin` is a slightly more restricted role where you can view all processes (and end them) but not modify server settings. However, the basic fact remains that you'll need a user with `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission, whether granted through one of the fixed roles or otherwise. A more restricted setup where you can be granted permission to *only* view everything in `sys.sysprocesses` through a stored procedure is [possible, but fraught with peril](https://sqlstudies.com/2014/02/26/impersonating-a-server-level-permissions/).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - trustyworthy works, but is a rather large hammer. I detail a code signing approach below that gets by with much less.

Answer (score 3):

You can use code signing to accomplish what you're looking to do. Here's the code:

```
CREATE LOGIN [normalUser] WITH password = 'f00bar!23'
CREATE USER [normalUser]
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE [codeSigningCert] WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate for code signing', EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-01-01'
CREATE LOGIN [codeSigningLogin] FROM CERTIFICATE [codeSigningCert]
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [codeSigningLogin]
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.processesProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.sysprocesses AS s
END
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.processesProc TO [normalUser]
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'normalUser'
GO
EXEC dbo.processesProc
GO
REVERT
GO
ADD SIGNATURE TO processesProc BY CERTIFICATE [codeSigningCert]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.processesProc TO [normalUser]
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'normalUser'
GO
EXEC dbo.processesProc
GO
REVERT
GO
```

By way of explanation, I'm creating an unprivileged login/user and a stored procedure for them to run. Without signing the procedure, the select exhibits the normal behavior (that is, it only displays the current process. But once I add a signature to the procedure using a certificate that has an associated login with the proper permissions, the result set blossoms.

Note: I created the procedure in `master` because I'm lazy. You can create the procedure anywhere you want so long as the certificate exists in the database you're creating the procedure in (so you can add the signature). Lastly, one gotacha with code signing is that the signature is lost when the procedure is modified. This makes sense as the signature is an attestation of the contents of the proc at the time of signing. If the body is changed, it will need to be re-signed.

Comment: this is very nice. But can someone with dbo privliges create and run this?

Comment: Someone with sysadmn will need to create the logins and install the certificate in master. Asysadmin *could* run the proc, but why would they? They can access the data without jumping through hoops! Generally speaking though, the normal "who can execute the procedure?" is it different for this procedure than any other.

Comment: I should have been clearer in the problem statement. I have access to many machines with dbo access. I need to determine a user (before dropping the user ) is connected. I cannot get SA access. I gave you 10 points for a great solution but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: If you're asking "can I get permission to view sys.sysprocesses *without having to interact with someone who has the ability to grant some sort of access*?" the answer is "no; *someone* will have to do *something* to grant you access that you don't have"